# What is the Oracle equivalent of 'show tables' in MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle11g

There is all kinds of advice out there on the net as to how to see all the tables in an oracle database. I am very new to Oracle but if I create a 'database' which is known as an 'instance' in Oracle parlance, how would I find all the tables belonging just to that one instance as opposed to all of Oracle?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select *
from dba_tables
```

(Note that typically only the DBA role has access to that view).

If you actually want to see only the tables that are **owned** by the current user (not "the instance), use

```
select *
from user_tables;
```

To see the tables *accessible* by the current user, use:

```
select *
from_all_tables;
```

For more details, see the manual:

- [DBA_TABLES](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-480A67CD-39FD-40B8-9395-164E92E439E6.htm#REFRN23286)
- [USER_TABLES](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-564CEA73-E79E-4664-AC32-0CBAB817CF5A.htm#REFRN26286)
- [ALL_TABLES](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-6823CD28-0681-468E-950B-966C6F71325D.htm#REFRN20286)

Comment: Thank you. However those are 'built in' oracle tables. But what if I were to create a database called 'mycompany'. How would I do the same for the 'mycompany' database?

Comment: Those views are ***always*** there. It's part of building the database

Answer (score 4):

I think the term you're looking for is "schema" or "user", not "database". Tables are described in three [data dictionary](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/toc.htm) views:

[USER_TABLES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_5480.htm#i1635629): All tables belonging to the current user

[ALL_TABLES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_2117.htm#i1592091): All tables visible to the current user

[DBA_TABLES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_5056.htm#i1627762): All tables in the database, across all users, including those owned by SYS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you looking for `select table_name from tabs;`